# Move Analytics history from a property into a view?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions

I have three subdomains on my site, and three separate Analytics properties for them.

I now realise that they should all be in the same property, with a separate view for each subdomain, so that I can track users and conversions across the subdomains.

Is there any way I can move the Analytics history for the three separate properties into three views within the same property?

Comment: I don't think so.   I've never found any sort of migrate or import functions in GA.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you understand it wrong. A view is a kind of filter. A property is bundled to tracking id. You have correct setup. If you would do like you want, you will be forced to divide traffic of each subdomain by filtering - its much more headache, as with the current setup.

What i would do on your place: create an additional property, implement its tracking code into all three subdomains, together with already implemented tracking code. On this way you'll have one property for each subdomain, and one property for all subdomains.